# How to fix my terminal system wide proxy settings set by Fiddler?

Tags: curl, proxy, mono, wget, fiddler

In order to analyze HTTP package, I install Fiddler and Mono. I have configured shadowsocks and proxychains, and it works well. But after I installed Fiddler, all doesn't work. such as curl wget and so on.

All it connects to `localhost:8888` and it couldn't download. I want to uninstall Fiddler and clear its configuration, reset my previous config connect to localhost:1080 by shadowsocks or by default with no proxy.

```
kinny@kinny-Lenovo-XiaoXin:~$ curl https://www.youtube.com
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 8888: Connection refused

kinny@kinny-Lenovo-XiaoXin:~$ proxychains curl https://www.youtube.com
ProxyChains-3.1 (http://proxychains.sf.net)
curl: (56) Proxy CONNECT aborted

kinny@kinny-Lenovo-XiaoXin:~$ wget https://www.charlesproxy.com/assets/release/4.0.2/charles-proxy-4.0.2.tar.gz
--2016-12-06 11:33:38--  https://www.charlesproxy.com/assets/release/4.0.2/charles-proxy-4.0.2.tar.gz
Connecting to 127.0.0.1:8888... failed: Connection refused.

kinny@kinny-Lenovo-XiaoXin:~$ proxychains wget https://www.charlesproxy.com/assets/release/4.0.2/charles-proxy-4.0.2.tar.gz
ProxyChains-3.1 (http://proxychains.sf.net)
--2016-12-06 11:33:47--  https://www.charlesproxy.com/assets/release/4.0.2/charles-proxy-4.0.2.tar.gz
Connecting to 127.0.0.1:8888... connected.
Failed reading proxy response: Success
Retrying.

--2016-12-06 11:33:48--  (try: 2)  https://www.charlesproxy.com/assets/release/4.0.2/charles-proxy-4.0.2.tar.gz
Connecting to 127.0.0.1:8888... connected.
Failed reading proxy response: Success
Retrying.

^C
```

So, as you can see, it sames that all network connect connect to fiddler localhost:8888. Is there any way to remove fiddler and reset my config? because before install Fiddler, all works well including shadowsocks proxy. I have tried to change /etc/wgetrc to set http_proxy to my shadowsocks localhost:1080, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you downloaded the 2013 alpha version for Linux.

In Fiddler folder there are the attach.script which changes system proxy settings to point to fiddler  and the detach.script which clears proxy configuration (sadly on this alpha build it does not restore your original proxy settings).

So if you manually run detach.script Fiddler will no longer be configured as proxy via gsettings. If you had other proxy configured before running Fiddler you will have to manually put it back.

Answer (score 0):

I was afflicted by this as well.

I had installed fiddler on ubuntu (my host os) a while back before giving up & just running fiddler in a windows VM.

Unfortunately, the ubuntu installation has undesirable side effects.

I noticed that command line tools like npm and curl on the host OS kept trying to connect through 127.0.0.1:8888 and failing.

Eventually I tracked it down to the following 4 entries that the original fiddler install must've added to my .bashrc:

```
export http_proxy='127.0.0.1:8888'
export https_proxy='127.0.0.1:8888'
export ftp_proxy=''
export socks_proxy=''
```